# Symmetric and positive-definite matrix: bound on linearly-independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a **symmetric** and **positive-definite** matrix. Let $x$ and $y$ be **linearly independent** vectors.

I want to prove that $|x^t Ay| < \sqrt{x^t Ax \cdot y^t Ay}$

From the definitions I know that:

- $x^t A x > 0$
- $y^t A y > 0$

for all $x, y$.

Also, since they are linearly independent: $\alpha x + \beta y = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = \beta = 0$.

I have been trying with different inequalities, attempting to get a bound that uses the positive-definite inequalities, but I don't get anywhere.

What else could I try?

Comment: What inequalities have you tried?

Comment: For instance, I tried starting with $|x^t Ay|$ and adding the missing terms to get the positive-definite inequality. But that doesn't add new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A=B^TB$ for some nonsingular matrix $B$.

Let $x,y$ be non-null vectors.

Then, $x^TAx=x^TB^TBx=(Bx)^T(Bx)=u^Tu$ and $y^TAy=v^Tv$ where $v=By$

Now, $(u^Tu)(v^Tv)\ge (u^Tv)^2$ by C-S inequality

$\Rightarrow (x^TAx)(y^TAy)\ge (x^TAy)^2$

Here '$=$' does not hold precisely because $x,y$ are not linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks. How is it that you can apply C-S? $(u^t u) = <u, u>$ and the same for $v$ right?

Comment: By C-S, $(\sum_i u_i^2)(\sum_i v_i^2)\ge (\sum_i u_iv_i)^2$ . So the lhs can be written as above because $u,v$ are column vectors.

Comment: Got it! One more thing: would considering the function $f(\lambda) = (x+\lambda y)^t A (x+\lambda y)$ make things easier for the proof?

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Interesting that this approach does not need symmetry of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Verify that $\langle x, y \rangle = x^TAy$ is an inner product.

Try Cauchy-Schwarz. (Recall when does equality doesn't hold for Cauchy-Schwarz).

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ are associated with different eigenvalues of $A$, then $x \perp y$, and $x^{T}Ay=\lambda_{y}x^{T}y=0$.

If $x$ and $y$ are associated with the same eigenvalue, $\lambda$, then 
$x^{T}Ay=\lambda x^{T}y$, and $| x^{T}Ay | \leq \lambda \| x \| \| y \|$ with equality only when $x \parallel y$ (which can't happen since $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent.)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that with that definition you get the simplest proof: one line.