# Showing $(x^\top A^n x)(x^\top x)^{n-1}\geqslant(x^\top Ax)^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for an elementary proof of the following:

> Let $x$ be a $k\times 1$ column vector and $A$ be a square symmetric matrix of order $k$, with all elements of $x$ and $A$ non-negative. Then for any positive integer $n$,
>
> $$(x^\top A^n x)(x^\top x)^{n-1}\geqslant(x^\top Ax)^n$$
>
> with equality if and only if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

I prefer not to do this by induction. So it felt like I have to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But then I was looking at the result [$(x^\top Ax)(y^\top Ay)\geqslant (x^\top Ay)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432112/symmetric-and-positive-definite-matrix-bound-on-linearly-independent-vectors/) for a positive definite matrix $A$, which is seemingly nowhere near the desired result.

I then looked at the equality case to see if I can do this.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$, then we have

$Ax=\lambda x\tag{1}$

Premultiplying $(1)$ by $x^\top$, we get $x^\top Ax=\lambda x^\top x$.

From $(1)$ we again have $A^nx=\lambda^n x$, so that $x^\top A^nx=\lambda^nx^\top x$.

So, the l.h.s of the desired inequality becomes $$(x^\top A^n x)(x^\top x)^{n-1}=\lambda^n(x^\top x)^n$$ while the r.h.s is simply $(x^\top Ax)^n=\lambda^n(x^\top x)^n$.

But I need a hint on how to prove the strict inequality in general. I wonder if any results from extrema of quadratic forms would come in handy.

Apparently this inequality occurs somewhere in genetical theory ([Mulholland and Smith, 1959](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309342)). There is a proof of this inequality in the cited paper but I haven't gone through it.

Comment: The paper you linked to is about the inequality $(x^\top A^n x)(x^\top x)^{n-1}\geqslant(x^\top Ax)^n$; there you have the equality when $x$ is an eigenvector, and moreover it is homogeneous (unlike yours). Are you sure about the inequality you want to prove?

Comment: @ArnaudD. While that is true, I have taken the problem from a book which cited that paper. The problem statement I have posed here is the one from the book.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the book has a typo. For a fixed $n\geq 3$, the LHS is like a multiple of $\|x\|^4$ and the right-hand side is like a multiple of $\|x\|^{2n}$, so the RHS should grow with $\|x\|$ faster than the LHS.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I have edited my post. Thank you for pointing out the typo.

Comment: "for any integer $n$"? This is not true for $n=-1$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, at least.

Comment: Actually, $n = 3$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ also makes a counterexample. Or do you also want the entries of $x$ to be nonnegative?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Nothing is said about the entries of $x$.  But since you point out the counterexample,  I guess I have to add that condition too.

Comment: Are you sure that the entries of $A$ should be nonnegative, rather than $A$ itself being nonnegative semidefinite? The latter sounds like a more useful assumption (and the two things often share the same notation, obnoxiously).

Comment: @darijgrinberg It possibly is a careless problem statement in the book. But I stated it here verbatim.

Comment: Let's get the cat out of the bag before it suffocates: what book?

Comment: Okay, the Mulholland/Smith paper you've cited actually wants the entries of $A$ to be nonnegative, but it also wants the entries of $x$ to be nonnegative. So that's the first way of fixing the problem.

Comment: @darijgrinberg The book is not actually a linear algebra book. It's called 'Linear Statistical Inference and it's Applications' by C.R. Rao.